# Graphics don't appear when adding if statement in update() void

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, keylistener

I was working to create my first game with a simple 2d game engine. Anyways, each time I add if (input.KEY_RIGHT) x++;, the canvas doesn't load. It only shows the background of the JPanel. But when I delted if (input.KEY_RIGHT) x++;, it will work. PLease let me know why it doesn't work.

```
package net.james222.game;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


/**
 * Main class for the game
 */
public class Game extends JFrame
{       

public InputHandler input;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    boolean isRunning = true;
    int fps = 30;
    int windowWidth = 500;
    int windowHeight = 500;

    BufferedImage backBuffer;
    Insets insets;

    int x = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            Game game = new Game();
            game.run();
            System.exit(0);
    }

    /**
     * This method starts the game and runs it in a loop
     */
    public void run()
    {
            initialize();

            while(isRunning)
            {
                    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    update();
                    draw();

                    //  delay for each frame  -   time it took for one frame
                    time = (1000 / fps) - (System.currentTimeMillis() - time);

                    if (time > 0)
                    {
                            try
                            {
                                    Thread.sleep(time);
                            }
                            catch(Exception e){}
                    }
            }

            setVisible(false);
    }

    /**
     * This method will set up everything need for the game to run
     */
    void initialize()
    {
            setTitle("Game Tutorial");
            setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
            setResizable(false);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);

            insets = getInsets();
            setSize(insets.left + windowWidth + insets.right,
                            insets.top + windowHeight + insets.bottom);

            backBuffer = new BufferedImage(windowWidth, windowHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            }

    /**
     * This method will check for input, move things
     * around and check for win conditions, etc
     */
    void update()
    {
       if(input.KEY_RIGHT) x++;
    }

    /**
     * This method will draw everything
     */
    void draw()
    {              
            Graphics g = getGraphics();

            Graphics bbg = backBuffer.getGraphics();

            bbg.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            bbg.fillRect(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);

            bbg.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            bbg.drawOval(x, 10, 20, 20);

            g.drawImage(backBuffer, insets.left, insets.top, this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Painting is Swing is typically done withing the `paintComponent` method of a component extending from `JComponent` (typically `JPanel`)

You should never use `getGraphics`.  This is simply a snap shot of the state of the component after the last paint cycle and may return `null` if the component hasn't begin painted yet.  It's contents will also be overriden on the next paint cycle.

Start by taking a look at

- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

I would also encourage you to use the [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API over `KeyListener` (not that I can see you actually using any sort of input event handler at all)...

I would also encourage you to take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) as you are violating the single thread model of Swing.

Java/Swing is a complex API/framework with very specific requirements for it's use.  While it is extremely flexible, it does require you to understand how it works so you can take the fullest advantage of it.

I would put aside your gaming aspirations while you come to grips with these concepts as it will make your life a million times simpler